# Which part of iOS file system can I access?

Tags: ios, filesystems

I'm totally new to iOS development and was playing around with some ideas to learn the ropes. One thing I am trying to do requires me to run through the device file system in order to e.g. show info on file type occurrence (basic storage analytics so to say) etc. Or only access local text files (like emails) to analyse them.

After doing some research it seems to me that the system is pretty restricted. Is it possible to access files directly or ask the user for permission to do so?

Any direct help, hint or link would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Generally, no, your App is sandboxed, which only allows it to access areas within that sandbox.  Extensions do allow a limited amount of sharing, as does `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` and `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` App properties (see `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` for more details) but these are "opt-in" settings

Comment: No, you can only access files in your own app's sandbox.  You can use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to show a view where the user can select a file from the files app (which includes access to services like Dropbox and other storage providers that they have connected to).  You should start by reading the iOS Application Programming Guide from Apple